# Woocommerce Before Checkout Process

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to get the email address of the customer before the checkout process begin.
I am thinking to use this action: woocommerce_before_checkout_process
Can someone help me to get the customer billing email with this action?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
$_POST['billing_email']